# Yii Index View Data Rendering With Condition

Tags: yii-extensions, yii

I am new to yii framework i have created an yii web application  with one module .
Now my question is i have added an sample data into my module in my module i have an columns name,dept and and active ,i want to render the data in the grid view only the data where active=0 , Can anyone help me how to change the data rendering query and how to add the condition

```
<div class="block">
<div class="content">
    <h2 class="title">Users's details</h2>
    <div class="inner">
        <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
            'data' => $model,
            'attributes' => array(
                'user_id',
                'user_name',
                'userpass',
                'userdept',
                'active',
            ),
            'itemTemplate' => "<tr class=\"{class}\"><td style=\"width: 120px\"><b>{label}</b></td><td>{value}</td></tr>\n",
            'htmlOptions' => array(
                'class' => 'table',
            ),
        )); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your dataprovider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a criteria

```
$criteria->compare('active', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this in your search function:

```
$criteria->compare('active', '1');
```